# Preventing apps from invoking my Activity

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have an Activity X which is only accessible after you've entered a valid credential.

How can I prevent other apps from calling startActivity with an Intent pointing to X ?

e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, ActivityX.class );
startActivity( intent );
```

Basically I don't want Activity X to be exported to any apps except my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the "*Declaring and Enforcing permissions*" section of the [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) Android SDK documentation.

Comment: Thanks. It now throws a SecurityException everytime an app does not share a digital sig with my app.