# How do I prevent other android apps from accessing my activities

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an android app in which I define several different activities in the manifest.  Some of these activities have intent-filters that I use (such as ACTION_PICK).  These activities, because of the intent-filters, show up when other applications request an activity to handle an ACTION_PICK.  Is there some way to prevent this, so that my activities are not accessible to other applications?  I've already tried setting android:exported="false" in my activity, but that did nothing.

Comment: oops, just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571615/preventing-apps-from-invoking-my-activity/1571632#1571632

Is there any way to delete this question?

Comment: I've voted to close your question as a duplicate to the one you show as the answer. It will take 3 more votes to close it however.

Comment: Actually, the answer that mah posted is much more concise so maybe we should just keep this open.

Comment: Leave it open ... this is a "better asked and answered" version than 1571615.

Comment: I voted to close because you asked if there was a way to delete your question. There haven't been any further votes so if mah's answer is what you're looking for then accept it and the question/answer will stay for others to see in the future.

Answer (score 21):

You need to:
* define a permission (which is only available to applications having your signature)
* define that your application uses your defined permission
* require that permission for the activities you want protected. (Be careful to not require it for your main launch activity).

```
<!-- define a permission -->
<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.mypackage.MYPERMISSION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.MYPERMISSION" />

<!-- define an activity which can only be started through internal code -->
<activity android:name="..."
          android:permission="com.mypackage.MYPERMISSION" >
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: Just for completeness, the permission and uses-permission tags go inside the manifest tag, but outside the application tag, and the activity tag(s) go inside the application tag.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Dominic - yes, this is how my manifests look. Perhaps other positions can work as well but I haven't tried them.

Comment: While the title is limiting the scope explicitly to other apps, I think it's worth mentioning that it doesn't work when doing it via activity manager since it's a system-level process. (Terminal command example: "adb shell am start you.package/full.activity.name"). And make sure you are not trying to start it with another app signed with the same DEBUG keystore since it will match its signature!