# how can i know that app is open using play store open button from play store or click on app_icon from device in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags, detect

I've already one install app.i want to know when user open that app then from where it is open either from play store or using device app icon click.can i also want to when i open my app from other app then from which app using it open.can is it possible using flag or intent ? from where can i start it ? which type of code require ? i also want to know what background process will happen when open app through play store any type of help appreciate I'm new in android.

Comment: Do a quick google search for Android Intent Filters :)

Comment: can you give more idea ?

Comment: Ideas, yes. Code, no. I won't show you code until you show me code. You should look into your manifest and look at the intent filter used by the launcher looks like.

Comment: can i know that which app responsible to open my app ?

Comment: @Muhammad can i prevent to other app to open my app from that app.?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6460657/1939564

Comment: @Muhammad can i get information when one app is open from other then 2 app which( open after calling) get any broadcast or any message from opener app(1st app) ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Muhammad when play service try to launch my app then i want to dect it in my app

Comment: You mean opening installed app from Google Play? I don't think its possible!