# Preventing my activity from being called from other apps in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-permissions

I'm trying to prevent my app's activities from being called from other apps, by implementing the following in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.my.app.ONLYME"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.ONLYME" />
<application ... >
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:permission="com.my.app.ONLYME"
    />
```

I tried running this, and manually calling MyActivity with the following adb command:

```
am start -n "com.my.app/.MyActivity"
```

And it worked - MyActivity got called successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460559/how-do-i-prevent-other-android-apps-from-accessing-my-activities It won't restrict starting if You are starting it from terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that since I got the solution from that post lol.

Comment: You're very welcome. haha it happens, no worries