# Restrict your android activity to be accessible from other activity

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an Android activity defined in my Manifest:

```
   <activity
       android:name=“com.me.myapp.myactivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

           <data android:scheme="myapp" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

I want to restrict this activity to be accessible only to one other activity outside my app, let's call that activity `"com.others.theirapp.theiractivity"`. How do I accomplish this restriction?
I do not have any information about the other app and its activity, the only information I have is its activity name, "com.others.theirapp.theiractivity".

Comment: What do you mean by 'accessible'? You want to expose an activity to be 'launchable' from other apps but you want to specify which apps are eligible for calling it?

Comment: Yes @azizbekian

Comment: Do you have control over the other app that you want to grant access to? If so, is it signed with the same key?

Comment: I would use `<data android:mimeType="application/my_special_mime" />`. To start the activity, you will need to set something to the intent: `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/my_special_mime");` or `intent.setType("application/my_special_mime");`.

Comment: I do not have any information about the other activity/app apart from its identifier "com.others.theirapp.theiractivity"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460559/how-do-i-prevent-other-android-apps-from-accessing-my-activities

Answer (score 0):

There is basically two ways to handle this

1. If other app is invoking you app with `startActivityForResult` then you can use `getCallingPackage()` to get and check calling app package name
2. Other way is that you can pass a unique id in intent from calling activity to you activity and check its matching or not to ensure that its a trusted call (You have to secure this unique id so that other user can't spoof it)

Answer (score 0):

Permissions applied using the `android:permission` attribute to the  tag in the manifest restrict who can start that Activity. The permission is checked during `Context.startActivity()` and `Activity.startActivityForResult()`. If the caller doesn't have the required permission, then a `SecurityException` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest you can use Exported to false if that helps

```
<activity
        android:name=".UpdateActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```